# Image not showing in php with html

Tags: php, html

We have am html code saved as .php because it includes a form that requires php. However, the image we've inserted isn't displaying on the browser while everything else is. 
Here's our coding:

```
<IMG SRC = "D:\xampp\htdocs\1.jpg" width = "650" height = "400">
```

We also tried this :

```
<?php
$media = fopen("1.jpg", 'r');
echo $media;
fclose($media);
?>
```

However, it returns "resource id #3" and I don't know how/what else to do to display the image.

Please help.

Comment: Why are you accessing image with physical path?

Comment: Set your image full access path EXAMPLE PATH: /var/www/html/project/uploads/1.jpg.

Comment: In your first example, why are you using a file system path?  In your second example, that's not how you write an image to the output.

Comment: i think the root will be the localhost which is htdocs , check the config file

Comment: Also, due to the fact that browsers are fickle instruments, make sure you use the proper markup: `<img src="folder/image.jpg" width="650" height="400">` - that means no spaces in the HTML code. And really, no all-caps tags either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your script is inside a folder in htdocs folder USE

`<IMG src="../1.jpg" width = "650" height = "400">`

else if your script is inside htdocs folder USE

`<IMG src="1.jpg" width = "650" height = "400">`

Answer (score 0):

Let image the directory-

```
D -> xampp 
-> htdocs
         -> 1.jpg
         -> file.php
```

then you can access your image as:

```
<img src="1.jpg" alt=""/>
```

if image is inside any folder like upload then

```
<img src="upload/1.jpg" alt=""/>
```